# Find the number of occurrences of a node in an xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file in the following format:-

```
<EticketCanStatusRes>
        <ETicket>
          <eticketno>asdf4511</eticketno>
          <flightuid>57490</flightuid>
          <passuid>91832</passuid>
          <PnrNumber>AADS12</PnrNumber>
          <Origin>COK</Origin>
          <Destination>DEL</Destination>
        </ETicket>
         <ETicket>
          <eticketno>asdf4511</eticketno>
          <flightuid>57490</flightuid>
          <passuid>91832</passuid>
          <PnrNumber>AADS12</PnrNumber>
          <Origin>COK</Origin>
          <Destination>DEL</Destination>
        </ETicket>
</EticketCanStatusRes>';
```

I need to find out how many `<ETicket>` elements there are. In my example there are 2.

Comment: How have you tried to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and [xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
$string = '<EticketCanStatusRes>
        <ETicket>
          <eticketno>asdf4511</eticketno>
          <flightuid>57490</flightuid>
          <passuid>91832</passuid>
          <PnrNumber>AADS12</PnrNumber>
          <Origin>COK</Origin>
          <Destination>DEL</Destination>
        </ETicket>
         <ETicket>
          <eticketno>asdf4511</eticketno>
          <flightuid>57490</flightuid>
          <passuid>91832</passuid>
          <PnrNumber>AADS12</PnrNumber>
          <Origin>COK</Origin>
          <Destination>DEL</Destination>
        </ETicket>
</EticketCanStatusRes>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$result = $xml->xpath('//ETicket');
echo count($result); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you juste want a statistic about only one type of node without relative restriction, DOM::getElementsByTagName would be sufficient as it returns a DOMCollection which has a "length" read-only attribute.

```
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->load("your file.xml");
echo $document->getElementsByTagName('tagname')->length;
```

If you want to provide more restrictions, you can use XPath with SimpleXML like @Arkh said, or with DOMDocument.

Answer (score 0):

I took the xml file and php file in the same directory, so, the code is like this

```
     <?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
// load the XML string defined above
$dom->load('tiket.xml');


$etickets = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ETicket');
$count = 0;

foreach ($etickets as $etiket) {
    $count++;
}

echo $count;
?>
```